# Permissions error while setting up kubernetes pod

Tags: debian, google-compute-engine, kubernetes

I am a newbie to kubernetes and docker and I am following the tutorial at https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-wordpress
which teaches how to setup a pod running wordpress.

I have setup a GCE instance and have logged into my debian instance and installed docker and kubernetes. But when I specify a file to be used by kubectl, I get a permission error. The command I issue is:

```
sudo kubernetes/platforms/linux/amd64/kubectl create -f wordpress.json
```

The error I get is:

```
Error: Post http://localhost:8080/api/v1beta1/pods?namespace=default: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
```

What am I doing wrong? I suspect a firewall permissions error and I added the following firewall rule to my instance setting.

```
Source Ranges: 10.0.0.0/8
Allowed Protocols and Port: tcp:1-65535;udp:1-65535;icmp
```

Comment: How did you install Kubernetes on your GCE instance? Did you run the curl command from the GCE getting started guide (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/gce.md)?

Comment: @RobertBailey: Yes I ran curl -sS https://get.k8s.io | bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the simplest getting started experience on Google's cloud platform, I'd recommend using [Google Container Engine](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/) to get your cluster up and running.

With one click or a single command line (`gcloud alpha container clusters create NAME --zone ZONE`) you can deploy a cluster and get yourself up and running quickly. This allows you to focus your time on using Kubernetes rather than installing Kubernetes.

Comment: I logged into the head cluster, created the json file and run "kubectl create -f wordpress.json" and got it to work. Is this what you mean? I felt like I cheated though..

Comment: You can run kubectl on the master because kubectl defaults to connecting to port 8080 where the master happens to host a local apiserver. But this isn't the intended use for kubectl (you should be able to run it on your local machine as well). Based on your error it looks like you didn't get a valid kubeconfig file (look in ~/.kube/config) for your cluster. You could try to delete and recreate your cluster to see if that helps. From the kubernetes directory that the shell script downloaded run ./cluster/kube-down.sh; ./cluster/kube-up.sh.